# Как очистить оперативную память компьютера? [Python]

Tags: python, python-2.x

Как сделать сценарий, который очищает оперативную память?
Наподобие этой программы https://github.com/henrypp/memreduct/

Comment: Ну допустим ты очистишь файловых кэш. И тем самым освободишь пару Гигов, а зачем? Если хочешь свободную память вытащи её из компа и положи на стол рядом с собой.

Comment: Предложу вам такой сценарий: 1.  vi mem 2. Пишешь код 3. Сохраняешь 4. Запускаешь

Comment: А что значит "очистить"? Вообще-то в оперативной памяти расположены процессы, которые в настоящий момент времени имеются, т.е. ранее были запущены,  в системе. Включая системыне процессы, запущенные в момент старта операционной системы.  Удалите процесс - его память освободиться и отследит это сам операционная система. Выключите компьютер -  и вся память будет свободной. В чем проблема-то?